# Exactly-once processing in Kafka with replay

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am using Kafka for my event log/processing. I am looking for (as close to) exactly-once processing as I can get whilst supporting "replays" during partition (re)assignment, notifying the event handler of a replay so it can rebuild it state

Here is my code:

```
private final KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;
private final KafkaProducer<String, String> producer;
private final BiFunction<String, Boolean, String> eventHandler;
private final long[] startingCommitOffsets;

public void onParitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
  partitions.forEach(p -> startingCommitOffsets[p.partition()] = consumer.position(p));
  consumer.seekToBeginning(partitions);
}

public void run() {
  while (true) {
    var records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(Long.MAX_VALUE));
    var commitRecords = new HashMap<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata>();

    producer.beginTransation();

    records.forEach(r -> {
      var isReplay = r.offset() < startingCommitOffsets[r.partition()];
      var resultEvent = eventHandler.apply(r.value(), isReplay);
      producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(r.topic(), r.key(), resultEvent));

      if (!isReplay) {
        commitRecords.put(new TopicPartition(r.topic(), r.partition(), new OffsetAndMetadata(r.offset()));
      }
    });

    producer.commitTransaction();

    if (!commitRecords.isEmpty()) {
      consumer.commitSync(commitRecords);
    }
  }
}
```

My questions:

1. When the partition is assigned, I save the current position and seek to the beginning. This doesn't changed the committed position does it? (The docs weren't clear)
2. `product.commitTransaction()` and `consumer.commitSync()` are two separate operations. If the later fails, we would have already committed some new events which will be duplicated next time the events are processed - is there any way to combine these into one operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the partition is assigned, I save the current position and seek
> to the beginning. This doesn't changed the committed position does it?

Committed position doesn't change until you explicitly call `commitAsync() or commitSync()` or `auto.commit.enable=true`

> `producer.commitTransaction()` and `consumer.commitSync()` are two separate
> operations. If the later fails, we would have already committed some
> new events which will be duplicated next time the events are processed
> Is there any way to combine these into one operations?

```
producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction()
```

This method might be the one your are looking for to achieve exactly once processing.

From the [documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/2.1.1/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#sendOffsetsToTransaction-java.util.Map-java.lang.String-):

> Sends a list of specified offsets to the consumer group coordinator,
> and also marks those offsets as part of the current transaction. These
> offsets will be considered committed only if the transaction is
> committed successfully. The committed offset should be the next
> message your application will consume, i.e. `lastProcessedMessageOffset+1`.

*More importantly,*

> Note, that the consumer should have `enable.auto.commit=false` and
> should also not commit offsets manually (via sync or async commits).

---

You can deduce the `TopicPartition` and offset from `ConsumerRecord` which you will get as a result of `poll()`.

Just store them (`new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition())` and `new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset())`) in a map and pass it when you would want to commit.

Following code snippet can get you an idea ([reference](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/)):

```
KafkaProducer producer = createKafkaProducer(
  “bootstrap.servers”, “localhost:9092”,
  “transactional.id”, “my-transactional-id”);

producer.initTransactions();

KafkaConsumer consumer = createKafkaConsumer(
  “bootstrap.servers”, “localhost:9092”,
  “group.id”, “my-group-id”,
  "isolation.level", "read_committed");

consumer.subscribe(singleton(“inputTopic”));
    while (true) {
      ConsumerRecords records = consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);
      producer.beginTransaction();
      Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
      for (ConsumerRecord record : records) {
        producer.send(producerRecord(“outputTopic”, record));
        map.put(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()), new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset()));
      }
      producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(offsetMap, group);  
      producer.commitTransaction();
    }
```

After sending the offsets, we commit them.